# How can I get a list of linux users/group?

Tags: linux

I need to get and filter the linux users list like:

```
username1 username1_group
username2 username2_group
...
usernameN usernameN_group
```

I've tried, but only that I've found is:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep /home | cut -d: -f1
```

It gives me the list of users in /home folder. But how can I add the group name to each of them?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}' | while read name; do groups $name; done
```

Comment: Or just `getent passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}'` for a plain list of groups.

Comment: @Andrejs: That lists users. I think you mean `getent group...`

Answer (score 3):

```
getent passwd
```

... and cut what you need.

Also, getent has the advantage that it will look at all databases on the system. /etc/passwd only contains information for local users but not other places like LDAP, NIS, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The list of groups is `/etc/group`.

To get a list of the groups that a specific user is in, you can run

```
$ groups username
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at /etc/group